# In a WebBrowser control, window.external is not available

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'd like to call C# methods within a WebBrowser Control. Below is my code:

In XAML,

```
<phone:WebBrowser Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="WebBrowserForDetails" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" ScriptNotify="WebBrowserForDetails_ScriptNotify" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

In C#,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    string html = string.Format("<html><head><title></title><script type=\"text/javascript\">{0}</script></head><body><button onclick=\"call();\">Push</button>", "function call(){ window.external.notify(123) ;}");
    WebBrowserForDetails.NavigateToString(html);
}

private void WebBrowserForDetails_ScriptNotify(Object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```

Expected to see `123` in the debug window.

When the `<button>Push</button>` is pushed, `window.external.notify` is never called. In fact, `window.external` is not available. I would like to call the `window.external.notify` function from the WebBrowser control to call the `WebBrowserForDetails_ScriptNotify` method. What should I do?

**Edit**

Reference links: [MSDN: `window.external.notify`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [Any way to set the WP7 Webbrowser control height Dynamically and lock scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684307/any-way-to-set-the-wp7-webbrowser-control-height-dynamically-and-lock-scrolling) and [Displaying HTML Content in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: I assume you mean Windows-Phone-7? not Windows-Mobile.  For future reference we prefer that the content of a stackoverflow question actually contain a question.  Your is a statement of fact.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Yes, I am talking about WP7. Also I edited the question to be a question. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right, but window.external.notify() method is takes String parameter, not Integer. Try window.external.notify('123') call instead.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that `window.external` returns nothing but empty so I can't even get down to `window.external.notify`

Comment: There is test project that works for me: http://www.fileserve.com/file/BhVhMAZ/HTML.zip

Comment: File not available anymore... please provide code or new link!

Comment: Sorry, haven't a copy of this project. The main difference between topic project is to pass a number as a string --> '123'

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue is due to not providing a valid HTML5 document as your (body & html) elements aren't closed.

Comment: +1 For the final point, but you need to read the code in the question more closely, neither of your first two points is true.

Comment: It's not a HTML5 doc. I didn't declare the doctype: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`. According to HTML4 spec (and HTML5 spec, too) you don't need closing body and html tags. Although I put closing tags, I still `window.external` gives an empty value :(

Answer (score 0):

First off you probably want to read what Mike Taulty comments on offline browser content.

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/06/22/silverlight-html-and-the-webbrowser-control-for-offline-apps.aspx